# LibGDX ShapeRenderer. Пиксели дрожат при движении shapeRenderer.circle

Tags: java, libgdx

Всем привет! Хочу сделать программку, которая сохраняла бы предыдущие движения shapeRenderer.circle (Наподобие вот этого https://youtu.be/rqecAdEGW6I?t=403). Все бы хорошо, но пиксели у этого круга в libGDX начинают дрожать, т.е. самые крайние пиксели то исчезают, то появляются.

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    ShapeRenderer shape;
    int x,y;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        shape = new ShapeRenderer();
        x=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2;
        y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        int stepX=random(2)-1;
        int stepY=random(2)-1;
        x+=stepX;
        y+=stepY;
        shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shape.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        shape.circle(x,y,3);
        shape.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        shape.dispose();
    }
}
```

Пытался запустить приложение на андроиде, но андроид вообще не сохраняет прошлых состояний и работает так, как будто я не комментировал эти строки кода:

```
    //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Не могли бы объяснить:

- Почему пиксели дрожат?
- Почему на андроиде приложение не сохраняет путь, пройденный circle. И что нужно сделать, чтобы он их сохранял?

Comment: Попробовал через pixmap, та же проблема.

Comment: Запустил этот код: 1) Никакого дрожание пикселей не было. 2) И на Андроиде все работает также, синие следы остаются